# How to name a rosserial_arduino node?

Tags: rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you give a name to a rosserial_arduino node? There are several [good examples](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials), but none of them specify a name, resulting in the published topics and listeners appearing in the root namespace.

Normally, a node's name is specified with `ros::init(argc, argv, "some_name");` but it doesn't look like rosserial_arduino supports this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254456/how-to-name-a-rosserial_arduino-node?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can chage the node name with an ros Lauch file

here my code in my Launch file:

```
<node pkg="rosserial_python" type="serial_node.py" name="serial_stepper_node">
  <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2017-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2017-02-12**:
Apparently, I can also do the same thing with a `<group ns="some_name">` tag.